# Postgres streaming using JDBC Kafka Connect

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, apache-kafka-connect

I am trying to stream changes in my Postgres database using the Kafka Connect JDBC Connector. I am running into issues upon startup as the database is quite big and the query dies every time as rows change in between.

What is the best practice for starting off the JDBC Connector on really huge tables?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't pause the workload on the database that you're streaming the contents in from to allow the initialisation to complete, I would look at [Debezium](http://debezium.io/).

In fact, depending on your use case, I would look at Debezium regardless :) It lets you do true CDC against [Postgres](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/postgresql/) (and [MySQL](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mysql/) and [MongoDB](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/mongodb/)), and is a Kafka Connect plugin just like the JDBC Connector is so you retain all the benefits of that.

Comment: To add to this answer, we've added support for providing specific select statements to be used during snapshots in Debezium 0.7.2 (look for "snapshot.select.statement.overrides" in the [connector docs](http://debezium.io/docs/connectors/postgresql/)). This might help to narrow down the dataset captured in a snapshot, e.g. to exclude logically deleted records.

Comment: Does the debezium connector use the WAL? If it queries the db too, then how does it deal with this?

Comment: @VineetGoel yes it uses the WAL but also a snapshot (depends on configuration) which is a select statement.